# error while running example of oozie job

Tags: hadoop, oozie, oozie-coordinator

I tried running my first oozie job by following a blog post.

I used **oozie-examples.tar.gz**, after extracting, placed **examples** in hdfs.

I tried running map-reduce job in it but unfortunately got an error.

Ran below command:

```
oozie job -oozie http://localhost:11000/oozie -config /examples/apps/map-reduce/job.properties -run
```

Got the error:

> java.io.IOException: configuration is not specified   at
>   org.apache.oozie.cli.OozieCLI.getConfiguration(OozieCLI.java:787)     at
>   org.apache.oozie.cli.OozieCLI.jobCommand(OozieCLI.java:1026)  at
>   org.apache.oozie.cli.OozieCLI.processCommand(OozieCLI.java:662)   at
>   org.apache.oozie.cli.OozieCLI.run(OozieCLI.java:615)  at
>   org.apache.oozie.cli.OozieCLI.main(OozieCLI.java:218) configuration is
>   not specified

I don't know which configuration it is asking for as I am using Cloudera VM and it has by default got all the configurations set in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> oozie job -oozie http://localhost:11000/oozie **-config** /examples/apps/map-reduce/job.properties -run

The **-config** parameter takes an local path not an HDFS path. The **workflow.xml** needs to be present in the HDFS and path is defined in the **job.properties** file with the property:

```
oozie.wf.application.path=<path to the workflow.xml>
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for correcting me. After running the same I am getting a file in /user/cloudera/oozie-oozi/0000004-160416014941788-oozie-oozi-W/mr-node--map-reduce/  which is action.xml.

How to get the actual output. As I am clueless over here again.

Comment: What is the output path of your mr job check that. It should be available in the workflow xml if you are not aware. Open the ui and check job definition.

Comment: If you can just enlighten my about the xml property to be used for referring mr job path please?

Comment: I was referring output path of the mr job in mr action configuration in `workflow.xml`. If you running the oozie map-reduce example then it should be `mapred.output.dir` -> `/user/${wf:user()}/${examplesRoot}/output-data/${outputDir}`

Comment: I have mentioned it earlier itself like below:

<property>
        <name>mapred.output.dir</name>
        <value>/word_dir</value>
</property>

Is It mandatory to refer it with a specific user as per the path you mentioned abve